# Hyper-v guest network priority

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012-r2

I have the following configuration:

2 Hyper-v hosts connected using a Dell 1gb switch:

Host 1 vms:

- domain controller which also server as dns server (DC01, ip: 10.2.2.5)
- fileserver (FS01, ip: 10.2.2.6)
- remote desktop session host(RDSH01, ip: 10.2.2.7)

Host 2 vms:

- remote desktop session host (RDSH02, ip: 10.2.2.8)

The hosts have a single external virtual network switch and the VMs is using a single NIC

RDSH02 has a mapped drive to the FS01.

When i transfer a file from RDSH02 to FS01 it gets approx 1gb speed going through the dell switch.

RDSH01 also has a mapped drive to FS01. However, with this one, i want to use a private virtual switch instead, so it doesn't go through the physical dell switch (since they're on the same host).

I've added the private virtual switch to host1 and assigned a nic on both FS01 and RDSH01 connected to this private switch. I've also set an IP 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3 respectively on the two VMS.

Now, using the mapped drive mentioned before (Z drive mapped to \fs01\rdsh01), what decides which network it picks for the transfer?

My ramblings:

1. It does a DNS lookup, finds that FS01 has 10.2.2.6 and picks that route for the transfer
2. Somehow it knows that it has a 'better' route and picks the private route (192.168.0.2)
3. I need to change the hosts files on both the vms to point FS01 to 192.168.0.2 on the RDSH01 (i really dont wanna do this)
4. Need to add an additional IP for fs01 in DNS and set some network binding order somehow

Basically, how do i get it to pick the private network?

Comment: There's no need to set up a second virtual switch. VM-to-VM traffic on the same host will never go through the physical switch - traffic will flow internally on the vm host.

Answer (score -1):

By design it will always pick the external switch ahead of the internal switch while both are up and connected. To force the use of the internal exclusively you will have to implement firewall rules to block communication between the host and vm on the external network.

See:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/035c0471-1792-4add-b602-9f38f9f2284a/internal-and-external-switches-on-server-2012-r2?forum=winserverhyperv

My solution is posted under the name **mercybrew** at the end of the thread

The adaptation to your situation should be as follows:

1. If you mapped the drive on RDSH01 to the share on FS01 by DNS name and still want that name to be used, you need to create static A record in your DNS zone for the DNS name of FS01, pointing to its private virtual switch interface IP - 192.168.0.2 since the interface will not be able to register itself in DNS (except of course if FS01 itself is a DNS server and you select to have the private interface participate in DNS processes). On the other hand, you could delete and remap the drive to FS01 explicitly by its private interface's IP (\192.168.0.2\sharename instead of \FS01.*domainname.domainroot\sharename*).

   2. From within the VM, use the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
      MMC to create a custom, port based rule under **Outbound Rules** with the
      following settings

      - Protocol Type: TCP
      - Local Port: Any
      - Remote Ports: Specific ports 139, 445
      - Local IP Address: 10.2.2.7
      - Remote IP Address: 10.2.2.6
      - Action: Block the connection
      - 10. Profile: All
      - Name: *As you find descriptive*
   3. Create a second custom, ports based rule but this time under **Inbound Rules** with the following settings

      - Protocal Type: TCP
      - Local Port: Specific ports 139, 445
      - Remote Ports: Any
      - Local IP Address: 10.2.2.7
      - Remote IP Address: 10.2.2.6
      - Action: Block the connection
      - 10. Profile: All
      - Name: *As you find descriptive*

You may need to restart the Windows Firewall service for the rules to take effect. Test that it works by copying a huge file a across the share and watching from Taskmanager to confirm that the private virtual switch based network interface is the one used.

Warning!!! This solution does not allow for fail-over if you disconnect or disable the private virtual switch interface of any of the two. All SMB based traffic between the two systems will permanently fail until the rules are disabled.

Comment: Adding that solution here would improve your answer.  Links do break and then your answer is less useful.